# What is the difference between 波にのまれる and 波にさらわれる?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

I encountered these 2 on a N1 聴解 practice test and even though I got the gist, I was wondering if there is a hidden implication/nuance, or if it was just a different way to say the same thing without sounding repetitive.

Here is the script:
[image]

As far as I can tell, both mean "swept away" by the waves and can be written with the kanji of 呑む and 浚う respectively.

Maybe 呑まれる (using the "swallow" kanji) is a bit closer to "swallowed" by the waves /sunken etc., while 浚われる simply means swept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm Japanese.

I feel these sentences like following.

> 波にのまれる

They were covered by waves.

Someone may survive own with luck.

> 波にさらわれる

The man was washed away.

It's difficult for him to survive.

He need both of super good luck and rescue to survive.

## Additional Feeling

> 波にのまれる

Depending on the sentence context, it's also possible that the surfer fell over in the waves.

> 波にさらわれる

washed away (ex. rip current)

Perhaps there may be a pattern of 「波にのまれる」then「波にさらわれる」.

Comment: ありがとうございます、大変参考になりました。